# Extend Linux partition without rebooting

Tags: linux, partition, disk-usage

I apologize if I say something wrong out of inexperience but I'm asking for help... because I understand nothing.

My computer has been partitioned so to have Windows 10 and Ubuntu years ago. Today, on Ubuntu, I was installing a few libraries when I realized I didn't have any more space in my disk. Is there a way to enlarge the memory available for Ubuntu without me needing to reboot the system? I really don't know how to do that and given the current situation (universities closed and so on) I can't find anyone who can physically help me.

I've been reading a few threads trying to figure my way out of it... but most replies were too technical and I couldn't understand them. I wonder if there's a step-by-step solution that I could try to follow by just paying attention at a few things.

Here is what I see on `Gparted`:
[image]

I should add that I really don't care about the Windows partition (or files or anything), but I need to solve this problem of memory urgently because is fundamental for my master thesis. I thank you so much in advance and hope that you can help me!!

Edit: `df -H`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           404M  1.9M  403M   1% /run
/dev/sda8        60G   49G  7.2G  88% /
tmpfs           2.1G  104M  2.0G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2       96M   96M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop4      172M  172M     0 100% /snap/spotify/41
/dev/loop3      9.6M  9.6M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/94
/dev/loop6       58M   58M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop5      365M  365M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/188
/dev/loop7       58M   58M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop8      9.6M  9.6M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop1      365M  365M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/179
/dev/loop0       96M   96M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/sda2       101M   32M   70M  32% /boot/efi
tmpfs           404M   54k  404M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1        32G  9.2G   22G  30% /media/nicolle/1015-2F26
```

Comment: it says you have close to 10GB free on / though?

Comment: I'd go for /dev/sda7, put an ext4 filesystem on it to house eg. /var or /opt, if those use a fair amount of room on your current system.  The 9.5Gb still free on  / are not enough for those few libraries you want to install ??

Comment: @frostschutz I've been removing a few libraries in a virtual environment to try to free some memory, but still I keep getting errors and notifications due to "no space left on device" when I try to pip install the libraries I need

Comment: @laineni Please, provide: `df -H`.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I just added it as an edit, thanks

Comment: @laineni Very strange question from me but is it really 7GB doesn't enough for libraries? Maybe problem in another case? Can you provide scenario with output of `no space left on device`? Please, put output as text as @roaima suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I'd love to see the scenario with `pip` generating the `no space` error, too, please. There looks to be plenty available.

Comment: I deleted a few other files I didn't need and finally got to install the libraries. Still it's very weird to me as the difference is not much wrt the 9Gb. I thought extending the partition could be a better solution, so that I wouldn't have the same problem in the future... but I installed them now. Thanks anyway to anyone who tried to help me :)

Comment: @laineni Maybe you find this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/119458) useful for future reading.

Comment: are you perhaps running out of inodes? `df -i`

Comment: _...  I realized I didn't have any more space in my disk. Is there a way to enlarge the memory available for Ubuntu without me needing to reboot the system?_  It ain't memory, it's disk space. Repartitioning the drive would need a reboot. Adding a new drive, even temporarily, by plugging in a USB external HDD, SSD, or Flash Memory Drive and copying files from the internal drive also makes more space, _without_ a reboot. Please run _lsblk | grep -v loop  && df -h | grep -v loop|tempfs|_ then highlight & copy the resulting text; return here, click [edit] & paste the text into your question.